# Add a second legend to display markers - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to add a 2nd legend to display the max values (via markers).

However, only the marker type in `mrkr` is given in the 2nd legend and not the desired symbol corresponding to `mrkr`.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(18, 4)), 
columns=list('ABCD'))
ax = df0.plot()

mrkr = ['o', '.', 'v', 'x']
mrkr_df = pd.DataFrame(mrkr)

idx_mx_vals = df0.abs().idxmax().to_list()

mx_vals = df0.to_numpy()[idx_mx_vals, 
np.arange(len(idx_mx_vals))].tolist()

for x, y, m, line in zip(idx_mx_vals, mx_vals, mrkr, ax.lines):
    line2 = ax.plot(x, y, marker=m, c=line.get_color(), markersize=20)

leg1 = ax.legend(loc='upper right')
leg2 = ax.legend(mrkr, loc='lower right')
# manually return leg1
ax.add_artist(leg1)
```

Desired Output:

```
2nd legend showing the markers with its symbol.
```

[image]

Comment: The error is due to the comma after line2 in the for loop, and line2 should hold a list of the labels that you want to output in leg2

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi:    Im not sure how to add a list of labels corresponding to the list mrkr. Some guidance would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
legend_elements = []
for x, y, m, line in zip(idx_mx_vals, mx_vals, mrkr, ax.lines):
    line2 = ax.plot(x, y, marker=m, c=line.get_color(), markersize=20)
    legend_elements.append(Line2D([0], [0], c=line.get_color(), marker=m, label=m))

leg1 = ax.legend(loc='upper right')
leg2 = ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='lower right')
```

Comment: @@Ze'evBen-Tsvi: I have update the original post. Now the 2nd legend appears but its not showing the symbols corresponding to the marker type.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you have to import Line2D from matplotlib.lines

Comment: Many thanks! What I needed.